# How to find a binary gap within a positive number n. Find the maximum length of the binary gap of the number

Tags: c#

```
public int solution(int N) {
    string result ="";
    int MaxLength =0;
    while (N > 0) {
        int remainder = N%2;
        result = remainder.ToString() + result;
        N/=2;
    }

    if(result != ""){
        string [] strArr = result.Split('1');
        if(strArr.Length >2){
            foreach(string str in strArr){
                if(str.Length > MaxLength)
                    MaxLength = str.Length;
            }
        }
    }
    return MaxLength;
}
```

> This code returns the maximum of the binary gap within a positive number. A binary gap is actually the maximal sequence of consecutive zeros that is surrounded by ones at both ends in the binary representation of N.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This might help with future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please ask a question when you post a question; don't just post an assignment. If you're having problems with your homework, we can help, but try to focus on a specific problem that you're having.

Answer (score 3):

This code takes into account the highl bit of negative numbers and works a little faster :)

```
public static int SolutionV2(int N)
    {
        int MaxLength =0;

        string strArray = Convert.ToString(N, 2);
        int count = 0;
        bool beginCounter = false;
        foreach(char bit in strArray)
        {
            if(bit == '1')
            {
                if (MaxLength < count) { MaxLength = count; }
                count = 0;
                beginCounter = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (beginCounter) { count++; }
            }
        }
        return MaxLength;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int solutionV3(int N) {
    string result = Convert.ToString(N, 2);
    int MaxLength =0;

    if(result != ""){
        string [] strArr = result.Split('1');
        if(strArr.Length >2){
            foreach(string str in strArr){
                if(str.Length > MaxLength)
                    MaxLength = str.Length;
            }
        }
    }
    return MaxLength;
}
```

Refactor code version you can use this code to get the max length of a binary gap.